# Remove everything betwen custom tags in php5

Tags: php

Hello I want to delete the content inside custom tags like this:

```
$string = "The sky is -start-content here-end- blue."

echo $string // results: The sky is blue.
```

Custom tags: `-start-` and `-end-`

I can't find the way to do this... anyone?? please... thanks you.

this worked:

```
$row = preg_replace('#(-end-).*?(-start-)#', '$1$2', $row);
```

Thanks you all! this worked.

Comment: This will be useful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php :)

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to match your example, since it leaves the tagss in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$haystack = "The sky is -start-content here-end- blue.";
$start = "-start-";
$end = "-end-";

$startpos = strpos ( $haystack , $start );
$endpos =  strpos ( $haystack , $end, $startpos ) + strlen( "-end-" );

$length = $endpos - $startpos;
$newhaystack = substr_replace($haystack, "", $startpos, $length);

echo $newhaystack;
```

Comment: Perfect example of using a bazooka to kill a fly. Using a regex would avoid all the extra code.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+-start-.*?-end-\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: Should be: `$string = preg_replace('/\s+-start-.*?-end-\s+/', ' ', $string);` You're missing a single quote.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. If you have enough privilege, you can suggest simple fixes like that by clicking on "edit".

Comment: Sure, will do that in future :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$a = explode("-start-",$string);
$b = explode("-end-",$a[1]);

echo $a[0].$b[1];
```

Comment: That work but is not what i am looking for...

I need something like:

$row = preg_replace('/-start[^>]*-([\s\S]*?)-\/end[^>]*-/', '', $row);

Comment: @user2369811 Can you update that into your question, and explain why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: $row = preg_replace('#(-end-).*?(-start-)#', '$1$2', $row);


Thanks you all! this worked.

Comment: That regular expression does not match the example string. Your end and start delimiter are the wrong way around, you're removing the bit you want to keep.

Comment: Actually this answer will give faster result then regex... it's way more better.